# Do letters of the alphabet have a gender?

Tags: genre, lexique, alphabet

For example, say you’re playing scrabble and you need the letter B. Would you say:

J'ai besoin d'un B.

Or

J'ai besoin d'une B.

Comment: They're all masculine. ***Un** A, **un B**, un **C*** etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'usage a effectivement consacré l'affirmation de @Laure en commentaires dans l'OP.

L'amateur de dictionnaires possède certainement un Littré et, au hasard de quelque page pourrait trouver, pour, par exemple *amonceler* et sa conjugaison : "*...quelques-uns mettent un accent grave et **une** seul**e** l.*"

Preuve qu'il n'en a donc pas toujours été ainsi. Certaines lettres (celles dont le nom commence par une voyelle (*effe*, *elle*, *emme*...) étaient anciennement des substantifs féminins.

Notez aussi, par pure curiosité, ce que dit Académie IV (1762) aux vedettes F, L, N, S... autrefois substantifs féminins, sont devenus masculins et se prononcent... *fe, le ne, se...*)

Comme quoi... on fait bien ce que l'on veut... puisque le genre, en français... est un choix arbitraire!

Mais oui! L'usage... emporté par la commodité... à tout embarqué sous un genre unique : Masculin! :

*J'ai besoin d'**un** B, d'**un** F, d'**un** L, d'**un** N... !* donc

(Mais personne ne vous en voudra jamais de dire que :

*J'ai besoin d'**une** L*)

Comment: C'est vrai qu'il ne faut qu'une L pour `voler`, bizarrement.